# Best way to add a year to a components text?

Tags: vb.net

Something I couldn't find (or just overlooked) in the documentation.

But I'd like to have a labels text contain the current year.

For now in my onload handler I am doing

```
 Me.lblInvoiceLine = "Please pay this by the end of " + Date.Now.Year.ToString
```

But I was wondering if there was a cleaner way. Just using the above as the components text attribute seemingly just gets the Date function treated as plain text.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. It's the purpose of every object's `ToString()` method to return an appropriate string representation of its (non-string) value(s).

Comment: @HelO'Ween I have multiple labels, so whilst this works perfectly I'd prefer to do this in the designer so it's limited to the designer view, rather than polluting my onLoad handler.

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property of the `Label` class can be overridden so you could create a custom control that automatically adds the current year to any text you provide, e.g.

```vb
Public Class YearLabel
    Inherits Label

    ''' <inheritdoc />
    Public Overrides Property Text As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.Text
        End Get
        Set
            MyBase.Text = Value & Date.Now.Year
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

You can add that class to your project and build to add it to the Toolbox. You can then add an instance to your form and set the `Text` property to `"Please pay this by the end of "` in the designer and you'll see exactly what you want. If you put the project away and then open it again next year, you'll see that the `YearLabel` has automatically updated.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like an interesting solution. Albeit I guess in this case it might be a bit overkill given it's just one addition, but for more complex cases it certainly seems useful!